# "List Index out of range"?

Tags: python, list, indexing

(PYTHON). I keep getting an error saying that 'list index' is 'out of range'. What does this mean? Here is the piece of code where it says the error is;

```
 products[L[0]] = {"desc" : L[1], "price" : L[2], "stock" : int(L[3]), "reorder" : int(L[4]), "target" : int(L[5])}
```

Problem section:

```
fi=open("data.txt", "r")  #Opens file in read mode
for line in fi: 
    L = line.rstrip().split(":")
    products[L[0]] = {"desc" : L[1], "price" : L[2], "stock" : int(L[3]), "reorder" : int(L[4]), "target" : int(L[5])}  #Reads file into a dictionary              
fi.close()  #Closes file
```

The text file to go with it (if you try the code make sure the two are saved in the same folder);

```
12345670:Burgers, £1:1.00:33:20:50  
34512340:Cheese, £2.50:2.50:11:15:30
98981236:Crisps, 0.55p:0.55:67:20:100
56756777:Spaghetti, £1.45:1.45:21:20:40
90673412:Sausages, £2.30:2.30:2:10:50
84734952:Lemonade, 0.99p:0.99:19:10:30
18979832:Ice Cream, £1.50:1.50:43:20:50
45353456:6 Pack of Beer, £5:5.00:16:10:30
98374500:Gum, 0.35p:0.35:79:10:90
85739011:Apples, 0.70p:0.70:34:20:50
```

I realize it's quite long however I don't know how to solve this problem and my so-called 'teacher' is not being very helpful.

Comment: it means that you are trying to access an index of your list that doesn't exist

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not just a code dump.

Comment: I tried running your code and got `IndentationError: unexpected indent` on line 1. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and try again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
@SirParselot already explained the bare message.  For example, if you have 10 elements in your list, your legal subscripts are 0-9.  If you try to get element 15, you'll get this error.

Comment: @SirParselot But which? In my text file there are 5 different colon separations each with information and the text file refers to it.

Comment: Does `L` have 6 items in it? If it has any fewer, then this is the source of your error.

Comment: I don't get any errors from running that code. How are you reading in the lines from the textfile?

Comment: @SirParselot: How did you guess what `L` is? I can't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: @jsfan I saw the original code which defined it

Comment: @SirParselot: I hadn't realised that the post had gone from "all script" to "less than minimum and no longer verifiable"...

Comment: try adding `if line:` before you call the split. I bet there is a `'\n'` at the end of your last actual line and it is trying to split a blank line

Answer (score 2):

You have likely defined `products` as a `list` and not a `dict`ionary. This causes problems because you are accessing large indexes on a list.

Let's look at an example of your first data line (and filling in the values on your assignment line):

```
12345670:Burgers, £1:1.00:33:20:50 

products[12345670] = {"desc" : "Burgers, £1", "price" : 1.00, "stock" : int(33), "reorder" : int(20), "target" : int(50)}
```

Notice that with this method, you are accessing the 12345670th element in the `products` *list*. That is a large list. If this is larger than your list, you'll get an `IndexError` saying that the index is out of range.

If, however, you were to define `products` as a dictionary (`products = {}` instead of `products = []`) this would work, as it would set the dictionary key of 12345670 equal to the value above.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a `'\n'` at the end of your last line which adds another blank line after it. You will need to ignore that case so you can do this

```
with open("data.txt", "r") as fi:  #Opens file in read mode
    products={}

    for line in fi:
         line = line.strip('\n') #Removes any new lines
         if line: #Checks if line is not blank
             L = line.rstrip().split(":")
             print L
             products[L[0]] = {"desc" : L[1], "price" : L[2], "stock" : int(L[3]), "reorder" : int(L[4]), "target" : int(L[5])}  #Reads file into a dictionary 

['12345670', 'Burgers, \xa31', '1.00', '33', '20', '50']
['34512340', 'Cheese, \xa32.50', '2.50', '11', '15', '30']
['98981236', 'Crisps, 0.55p', '0.55', '67', '20', '100']
['56756777', 'Spaghetti, \xa31.45', '1.45', '21', '20', '40']
['90673412', 'Sausages, \xa32.30', '2.30', '2', '10', '50']
['84734952', 'Lemonade, 0.99p', '0.99', '19', '10', '30']
['18979832', 'Ice Cream, \xa31.50', '1.50', '43', '20', '50']
['45353456', '6 Pack of Beer, \xa35', '5.00', '16', '10', '30']
['98374500', 'Gum, 0.35p', '0.35', '79', '10', '90']
['85739011', 'Apples, 0.70p', '0.70', '34', '20', '50']
```